# Condensate pump making loud noise

Tags: hvac, central-heating, central-air

Attached to my furnace, there is a Beckett CB151UL condense pump.  After every cycle of the furnace (either heat or cold) the pump, removes water from itself.  It has started doing a loud whining/grinding (I cant describe the actual sound).  I'm not quite sure what the problem is.  Perhaps someone can lead me in the right direction on how to diagnose the issue?

Here is a video of it making its noise.

https://www.youtube.com/shorts/_-Nr2IZZyLE

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is something caught in the impeller, or more likely, the bearings in the motor are worn-out.

Comment: And if cleaning it doesn't fix it, it is a $50 pump, and since it is external to the air handler, not hard to replace.

Comment: I ended up just replacing the unit!